# Making a dynamic URI in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, uri

I have some website `http://www.example.com`, I have a controller `abc` in which I have method **index()** which loads my website's view. I have made my controller `abc` as default controller so that when user enters `example.com` , he can directly see the view. I **cannot change** this default controller in any case. Now I want that if user enters `example.com/1234` , where 1234 is **profile number**, so it should show that profile . if it is `example.com/5678` , then it should show 5678's profile. The problem I am facing is , if user enters `example.com/1234` then it will throw a 404 error because I don't have any controller 1234, even if I make a check in my default controller's index function `if($this->uri->segment(3) == True)` it is throwing 404 error. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your routes file add this change:

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'abc/index/$1';
```

Then in abc controller:

```
public function index($profile=NULL)


    {

        $profile = $this->uri->segment(1, 0);

        echo($profile);// just for checking, of course, you will remove this later, + the rest of your code, related to user id
```

Comment: Thanks. But I think it will cause problem to other URLs which I have, like I have 5-6 other controllers , and their corresponding methods. So I cannot route any request to abc controller.

Comment: Hm...there shouldn't be problems, test it (i have tested), and since only numbers will be used in your profile url, you can use :num rather than :any wildcard.

Comment: CodeIgniter checks URI routing rules line by line. So you can put @nevermind's routing rule AFTER other controllers' routing rules. And it won't make any problem for other controllers (I think!).

Comment: For me it is creating problem, I added $route['(:any)'] = 'abc/index/$1'; at last of my routes.php file , it is routing every request to same controller abc. However if i change any to num , it is working fine except that it is not showing 404 error for the profile numbers which don't exists (profile number is 9 digit long) so if user enters 3 digits , it is not showing 404

Comment: Check profile number and if it does not exist, use show_404() for displaying 404 page.

Answer (score 0):

Typically there is a one-to-one relationship between a URL string and its corresponding controller class/method.
In the routes.php (config folder) you can change the defoult controller and routing also. Read the Wildcards (secion) in documentation below
More informacion read the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But your answer is very confusing and you told almost everything that can be possible. Can you answer it more precisely ? I already have one of my controllers as default.

Comment: Read CI documentation in detail (URI Routing) and you will fix the problem. You have an example that show you the URI Segment and Routing too.

Answer (score 0):

Create a **pre_controller** hook in **config/hooks.php**. Remember to enable hooks in **config/config.php** if you haven't already.

Example:

```
$hook['pre_controller'][] = array(
                                'class'    => 'Thehook',
                                'function' => 'check_for_profile',
                                'filename' => 'thehook.php',
                                'filepath' => 'hooks'
                                );
```

Then create your hook method **check_for_profile()** in **hooks/thehook.php**. This method can check for a matching profile and display or redirect accordingly. If no profile match is found you can call the **show_404()** method.

This way, your existing controller/method paths are unaffected, and all of your routes remain intact.

If you're redirecting within the hook, use this format:

```
header("Location: controller/method");
```

..rather than

```
redirect('controller/method');
```

...as the latter will result in a continuous loop

Answer (score 0):

Add in routes.php

```
$route["(.*)"] = 'abc/userid/$1';
```

Then in main controller abc add

```
public function userid()
    {
     $userid=$this->uri->segment(1);
echo ($userid);
    }
```

Now you have userid in this function :)